# Pandas question: How can I convert series of data to columns - series data made by groupby().count_values()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe - df

```
grouped = df.groupby('run')
s = grouped['chip'].value_counts()
```

then I get this, a series

What I have:

[image]

What I want is:

[image]

So I am guessing if I can change those series into columns then everything will be good.
any ideas?
Help needed thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try via `unstack()`,`rename()`,`rename_axis()` and `reset_index()` method:

```
s=(s.unstack(level=1)
    .rename(columns=lambda x:'chip'+str(x))
    .rename_axis(columns=None)
    .reset_index())
```

Comment: Are you a genius??

Comment: @steveworkspace nope btw if it solves your query then you can try considering accepting this answer(click on the tick to make it green) to indicate others that the issue is solved...Thnx ***:)***

Comment: but I think it's not same @KarnKumar

Comment: @AnuragDabas, its not same but it has nearby same approach [this may be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54863165/pandas-dataframe-to-convert-the-unique-value-as-column-name) , i appreciate your help though +1